# Testing linearity

Tags: model

I have two variables and I need to test if they exhibit a linear relationship so that I will be able to predict a response. Kindly assist in how to handle this problem. This is the data:task is to show that there is linear relationship between bricks used and wastes generated.

```
Trials            1       2       3       4       5       6       7        8
No. Bricks (x)  1400    1800    2100    2400    2700    3000    3500    3800
Wastage, % (y)  10.31   12.26   13.32   15.65   15.12   18.93   20.72   19.04
```

Comment: Is this for some subject?

Answer (score 2):

My first point would be that you do not need to have a linear relationship in order to predict a response.

Second, if you are trying to predict a response outside the range of the data (i.e. to less than 1400 or more than 3800 bricks) be very cautious.

To your question: The first thing I would do is make a graph. In `R` this could be done as follows:

```
x <- c(1400, 1800, 2100, 2400, 2700, 3000, 3500, 3800)
y <- c(10.31, 12.26, 13.32, 15.65, 15.12, 18.93, 20.72, 19.04)
plot(x,y)
lines(lowess(x,y))
```

The last line adds a loess curve to the data. The relationship appears to be linear at the lower levels, but then flatten at higher levels of bricks.

I would not rely on any statistical test of linearity. With only 8 points, the deviation from linearity would have to be extreme for it to be significant and a much smaller deviation might be important.

Comment: Also, if one just wanted to see the linear regression: `lines(x, fitted(lm(y~x)))` would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Peter, You have put it right, i actually want to have a justification of using regression analysis to predict waste generation, im sorry for that ambiguity.one of the prerequisites for regression analysis is linear relationship among variables.so im i safe to proceed and assume a linear relationship in this data?

Comment: "Linear regression" does demand a linear relationship among variables, but that can be surprisingly nonlinear. e.g. you can include quadratic and cubic terms, for instance. In addition, there are non-linear regression models.